# Spring model and request objects

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

In Spring, why can't we simply use a request object to carry data around in the application? Why did we switch over to using a model object? Also I read on a popular Spring book that it is still a request object (even in a Spring application) that does most of the hardwork of carrying data. Does it mean that the models we create in Spring are somehow linked to a request object underneath the hood?

Comment: Your understanding is wrong. The model object is filled based on the request parameters. Ofcourse you could pass around the `HttpServletRequest` to all your methods but do you really want to ty your services, repositories to the web or should they don't care about if they are called from a web site, JMS, etc. It has all to do with proper application design/architecture. Your web layer should be nothing more than a thin integration/translation layer .

Comment: http://www.intertech.com/Blog/understanding-spring-mvc-model-and-session-attributes/

Comment: Could you explain what he means by "copying model attributes to httpservletrequest"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> In Spring, why can't we simply use a request object to carry data
>   around in the application?

You can use `HttpServletRequest` or even `WebRequest` as method argument and then inspect those two in order to extract the data out of it. For example, if you want to get the value of a query string named `page`:

```
@RequestMapping("/users")
public void listUsers(HttpServletRequest request) {
    String page = request.getParameter("page");
    ...
}
```

> Why did we switch over to using a model object?

You can simply read from a `HttpServletRequest` and finally write to a `HttpServletResponse` in any controller method but spring also provides nicer abstractions for handling typical web scenarios. For example if your `page` parameter is a required int parameter with the default value of `1`, you can simply write:

```
@RequestMapping("/users")
public void listUsers(@RequestParam(defaultValue = "1") Integer page) {
    ...
}
```

Spring automatically does all the string to int conversion and populating with default values for you. Or suppose you want to automatically validate your json or xml `Request Body` and return validation errors. With these higher abstractions you will define a `model object` that contains all the validation logic in it and simply add `@Valid` annotation before its reference it method arguments, that's it!

```
@RequestMappting(value = "/users", method = POST)
public void addNewUser(@RequestBody @Valid User user) {
    // automatically validates the user
    // and send validation error, if user wasn't valid
}
```

Of course you can do the same by inspecting `HttpServletRequest` but it would be so cumbersome.

> Does it mean that the models we create in Spring are somehow linked to
>   a request object underneath the hood?

They're not necessarily link to them but usually these model objects will be populated from request parameters.

For example, spring convert the request body to the method argument by using an `HttpMessageConverter`. `HttpMessageConverter` is responsible for converting from the HTTP request message to an object and converting from an object to the HTTP response body. For instance `FormHttpMessageConverter` converts form data to/from a `MultiValueMap<String, String>`. This class has a `read` method that reads the request body and converts it to a `MultiValueMap<String, String>`. This method looks like this:

```
public MultiValueMap<String, String> read(Class<? extends MultiValueMap<String, ?>> clazz,
            HttpInputMessage inputMessage) throws IOException, HttpMessageNotReadableException {

        MediaType contentType = inputMessage.getHeaders().getContentType();
        Charset charset = (contentType.getCharSet() != null ? contentType.getCharSet() : this.charset);
        String body = StreamUtils.copyToString(inputMessage.getBody(), charset);

        String[] pairs = StringUtils.tokenizeToStringArray(body, "&");
        MultiValueMap<String, String> result = new LinkedMultiValueMap<String, String>(pairs.length);
        for (String pair : pairs) {
            int idx = pair.indexOf('=');
            if (idx == -1) {
                result.add(URLDecoder.decode(pair, charset.name()), null);
            }
            else {
                String name = URLDecoder.decode(pair.substring(0, idx), charset.name());
                String value = URLDecoder.decode(pair.substring(idx + 1), charset.name());
                result.add(name, value);
            }
        }
        return result;
}
```

By `String body = StreamUtils.copyToString(inputMessage.getBody(), charset);`, it actually reads the request body and converts it to a `String`.

Comment: Could you please explain that last line "model objects will be populated from request parameters"